# This tag has been [level]led

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/level/info):

> This should redirect to [r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor).
>
> `level` is an `R` command used for factor variables.

However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) shows that around 90% of the questions are not in fact R related, but concern a wide variety of unconnected topics, as illustrated by 8 of the 10 most recent questions:

- [Java taking too long to render tiles from a PNG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100868/java-taking-too-long-to-render-tiles-from-a-png-image)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812320/hibernate-how-do-i-verify-for-second-level-cache-usage
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40706928/issue-with-api-levels-in-gradle-build
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213905/android-how-to-create-level-in-dynamic-grid-view
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134781/how-to-change-default-checkbox
- [Simple counting program issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102769/simple-counting-program-issue)
- [call requires API level 21 (current min is 17): android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.StateCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044880/call-requires-api-level-21-current-min-is-17-android-hardware-camera2-camerad)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792905/level-curves-with-pyqtgraph-isocurve

From the [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

- *Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?* - No, clearly not, it's more often applied to questions other than those for which the tag is meant to be used, and there is little commonality in that usage.
- *Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?* - Clearly [r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor) is on-topic, but [level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) itself means little to nothing. I know little of R, but I suspect an R user would use [r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor) if they found [level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) didn't exist. Views?
- *Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?* - Not in most cases, as no one would search for [level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) questions (save for the R usage, and then they could search for [r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor) as searching for [level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) now is pretty unhelpful). It has 13 followers.
- *Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?* - No, clearly not

If there's already an [r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor) tag, a reasonable heuristic would be to retag all those already tagged [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and [level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) to be [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and [r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor), and remove [level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) from the rest.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q : +52/-1. A1 (saying yes) : +2/-1

Comment: Reminds me of [tag:nested].

Comment: The pun level has levelled off.

Comment: I say we [level] the whole thing. Doing so would improve the site's quality [level].

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +94/-1. A1 (saying yes): 44/-2. A2 (saying yes): +24/0. The community has voted in favor of the burnination.

Comment: There’s also [tag:multi-level], equally useless.

Answer (score 45):

I think that we need to blacklist this tag too.

**Any tag called [level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) will be misunderstood and/or ambiguous, no matter how good the excerpt is.**

Comment: Blacklisting is expensive: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372121/should-burninated-tags-be-blacklisted-by-default

Answer (score 28):

I also support this burnination. The question already contains enough research about the tag used along with the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag. There are 78 questions out of 453 which are tagged with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), and these need to be retagged as [r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor). (Coincidentally, [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and [levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/levels) appear together in 200 questions, and many of those which are tagged [levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/levels) but not [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) are also related to R. That probably needs a retag and a synonym, but that's for another day).

Focusing on the other [375 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level+-r):

- [60 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level+android), that are tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). These are related to the different API levels and need to be tagged as [android-api-levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-api-levels) instead.
- [22 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level+logging) tagged along with [logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logging) need to be tagged [log-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-level) (I personally feel that the [log-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-level) is redundant, but given that there's a tag already, it's better to use that).
- [11 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level+isolation) are tagged with [isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isolation), where both the tags need to be removed and the [isolation-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isolation-level) tag needs to be used. This also includes the many [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) posts which are about the isolation levels, but not tagged as such.
- There are also many questions which are related to volume level, which should probably be tagged with [volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/volume).

The bulk of the other questions relates to "level" in a way that doesn't describe the contents of the post, and therefore the tag can just be removed in those places.

Comment: Most (if not all) questions tagged [r][level] can be retagged to [tag:r] [tag:r-factor] (though some of them are already tagged with [tag:r-factor]). The same is true for [tag:r] [tag:levels].

Comment: @Jaap I'm not so sure. Pretty much all R questions about levels are about factors, but the converse is by no means necessarily true. Only a subset of them are specifically about manipulating/ordering/adding/dropping/keep'ing levels. So suggest leaving \[[tag:r]\]\[[tag:r-factor]\]\[[tag:levels]\], where merited.

Answer (score 5):

[level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Most (if not all) questions tagged [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)[level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) can be retagged to [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) [r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor) (though some of them are already tagged with [r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor)).
- [60 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level+android), that are tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). These are related to the different API levels and need to be tagged as [android-api-levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-api-levels) instead.
- [22 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level+logging) tagged along with [logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logging) need to be tagged [log-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-level) (I personally feel that the [log-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-level) is redundant, but given that there's a tag already, it's better to use that).
- [11 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level+isolation) are tagged with [isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isolation), where both the tags need to be removed and the [isolation-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isolation-level) tag needs to be used. This also includes the many [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) posts which are about the isolation levels, but not tagged as such.
- There are also many questions which are related to volume level, which should probably be tagged with [volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/volume).

## Progress:

The [level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=level),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blevel%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blevel%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blevel%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blevel%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of burnination](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179599/burnination-progress-for-the-level-tag)

[image]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: For the subset of R questions specifically about manipulating/ordering/adding/dropping/keep'ing factor levels, I suggest tagging \[[tag:r]\]\[[tag:r-factor]\]\[[tag:levels]\], where merited i.e. replace \[[tag:level]\] -> \[[tag:levels]\]. Most R factor questions are however not specifically about manipulating levels, in which case follow your procedure.

Comment: @smci [tag:levels] needs a clean-up soon, it's got mostly R and a few questions from other tags. Probably it needs to be renamed to something like [r-levels]