# Inconsistent 'double greying' of tags and preformatted text

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

If I write `preformatted text` and [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags) the grey used is roughly the same, and they are both visible.

If I quote them, however, it looks (well, looked):

[image]

the grey of pre-formatted text is (correctly in my opinion) darkened, but the grey of tags is not, which makes it harder to read.

I think this is a (small) bug. Real life use case [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339421/should-we-level-level).

Note now it's fixed, it looks

> like this: `preformatted text` and [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags)

which is much better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added some styling so tags will show up darker.

With you in the next build.

Comment: Thanks - I'll be sure to try it.

Comment: works great, though I think clearing cache may be needed.

Comment: @abligh Yeah, looks like Meta doesn't have cache busting on the CSS file, it links to `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Sites/stackoverflowmeta/all.css`